# How can I set a ceratin time interval for reading input in my Arduino game?

Tags: arduino

I'm making a game with my Arduino Uno. 
4 leds on the breadboards are displaying a random binary number. 
The player needs to press the button to put in the number that he sees 
(for example, if the leds are 0011, push the button 3 times).
If he guessed right, he wins (another led blinks). If not, he loses (led turns on and stays on).

But I want the player to automatically lose if he hasn't pressed a button for two seconds.

But I'm really a beginner so bear with me.  Below I'll post what I've got so far. But it's not exactly working. When I turn it on, without me pressing the button, it just goes straight to "you win" and the next round. What am I doing wrong?

```
int led1 = 9;
int led2 = 6;
int led3 = 5;
int led4 = 3;

int ledResult = 13; //will blink when you won, stay on when you lost

int buttonPin = 2;
int val = 0; // variable for reading the pin status
int buttonPushCounter = 0;
int buttonState = 0;
int lastButtonState = 0;


long interval = 2000; 

long randomNumber;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); //starts serial communication

  pinMode (led1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (led2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (led3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (led4, OUTPUT);

  pinMode (ledResult, OUTPUT);

  pinMode (buttonPin, INPUT);

  randomSeed(analogRead(A0)); //the pin is unconnected so it'll return something random (0-1023)


}

void loop() {

randomNumber = random(1, 16);

  Serial.println("Random Numbers sequence"); //just for self-check
  Serial.println(randomNumber);

  if (randomNumber >= 8)
  {
    digitalWrite (led1, HIGH);
    randomNumber - 8;
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite (led1, LOW);
  }

  if (randomNumber >= 4)
  {
    digitalWrite (led2, HIGH);
    randomNumber - 4;
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite (led3, LOW);
  }

  if (randomNumber >= 2)
  {
    digitalWrite (led4, HIGH);
    randomNumber - 2;
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite (led1, LOW);
  }

  if (randomNumber = 1)
  {
    digitalWrite (led2, HIGH);
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite (led1, LOW);
  }



unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

if (currentMillis > interval) {
    Serial.println("You lost.");
    digitalWrite(ledResult, HIGH);

}else{

  //READ BUTTON STATE
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  // compare the buttonState to its previous state
  if (buttonState != lastButtonState) {
    if (buttonState == HIGH)
    {
      buttonPushCounter++;
      Serial.println("Button push counter:");
      Serial.println(buttonPushCounter);
    }
    // Delay a little bit to avoid bouncing
    delay(50);
  }
  // save the current state as the last state, for next time through the loop
  lastButtonState = buttonState;

  if (buttonPushCounter = randomNumber) {
    Serial.println("You won!");
    digitalWrite(ledResult, HIGH);
    delay(700);
    digitalWrite(ledResult, LOW);
    delay(700);
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("You lost.");
    digitalWrite(ledResult, HIGH);
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Your problem stems from this line `unsigned long currentMillis = millis();` .. [`millis`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Millis) returns the number of milliseconds since the program first ran (i.e. the monotonic time) ... your program is starting, executing to this line, then since it didn't take 2 seconds to get to this line the check `if (currentMillis > interval)` fails (because `currentMillis` is actually `<= interval`), so the 'win' code goes through ...

Comment: Oh, so, millis() is counting the time from the start of the program in general, not right after the leds ligh up and before a player presses a button?

Comment: You got it .. `millis` will always count up until it rolls over after about 50 days. So you'll need to rewrite your logic to take this into account; you could do something like `unsigned long start = millis();` and then poll for button press in a loop, and within the same loop do something like `if ((millis() - start) >= interval) { /* lose code */ } else { /* continue polling/win code */ }` .. does that make sense?

Comment: " (millis() - start) >= interval "   This part I don't get. If Millis() is a total time that's passed since th program started, and start = millis(), then it looks to me like we're substracting from millis() it's own value, so the answer should be... a zero?  >.<

Comment: Sorry, meant that to mean the `(millis() - start)` would be inside a loop that does some probing for the input (basically restructuring a lot of your code). The `start` would be the starting point to check against, then each time you call `millis() - start` you would get the total time since a user input within the probing loop

Comment: So you mean that if I create long start = millis() in a loop that probes for input, the start variable will hold value for the time that has passed since the probing loop started executing? And in the the "if ((millis() - start)..." the first "millis()" stands for the whole time that's passed since the execution of the game while start is the time that's passed since the startof the probing loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially you'll want to have a main loop that probes/polls for user input, and if there's no input from the user on probe, then check the current `millis` time against when you called it for start. This will give you the elapsed time since no input was detected. If the elapsed time is greater than your threshold, you break out of the loop and check a timeout flag to see if you proceed with the button validation code or branch to the "lose" code.

Without writing the whole thing, here's a C pseudo-code mock up of the idea (commented to explain):

```
void loop() {
    while (is_running) { // main loop
        unsigned long start = millis(); // get starting probe time
        bool timeout = false;
        while ((buttonState = probe_input()) == no_input_val) {
            /* probe_input function returned no input,
            so check for timeout. If the probe_input function
            did return a 'value', then this loop won't iterate
            and you can check the buttonState below */
            if ((millis() - start) >= interval) {
                /* millis is monotonic time, so calling it, then
                subtracting the value from the start value will give
                us elapsed time since user did not give input. */ 
                timeout = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!timeout) {
            /* button state/level code */
        } else {
            // lose code
        }
    }
}
```

Again, this is just pseudo-code and won't compile as you'd need to implement the `probe_input` function to poll for input, but it's more to illustrate what you'd need to do to get you moving in the direction you're wanting.

I hope that can help.

Comment: Eh, that actually creates more questions. (But it's not your fault, it's just that I'm such a noob).  In  "while (is_running) {" What is "is_running"? Is it a boolean? Is it a line to start the probe? Why do we need it? Won't it start working on itself?

Comment: But thank you, it did help. Now I have a better grast of millis(). :)